# How to generate DIV when the page on load using JQUERY?

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<div id = "newdiv">
</div>    
<?php 
    $qry = "SELECT * from contact Where CustomerID='57'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {         
?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function createDiv() {
        $('#newdiv').append('<div id="div"'+i+'" class="ex" style="text-align: left;"><div id="div"'+i+'" class= "square"><table border="0" class = "table" ><tr><td width="51">Name:</td><td width="141"><input type="text" size="10" class = "name"></td></tr><tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" size="10" class = "title"></td></tr><tr><td>Contact:</td><td><input type="text" size="10"  class = "contact"></td></tr></table></div><img class="myimage" ondblclick="changeimage(this)" border="0"src="images/white_contact.png" width="60" /></div>');
        $( ".ex" ).draggable({containment:'parent',cursor:'pointer',opacity:0.6});
        $( ".ex" ).droppable();
    }
    createDiv(); // will execute when it loads this line
</script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I wanted to Use a while loop of PHP to check the number of contact for Customer 57
for each Contact it find, it should generate one DIV, and so forth, and they should append to each other

My code Just not working, why is this so? I am using while loop to call the CreateDiv() function

Comment: why are you redeclaring the entire function in every while iteration?

Comment: the $.load() is built to do the exact same thing.. why aren't you  using that ??

Comment: its not working due to the fact you will have the same method redeclared multiple times in the same page.  Javascript won't allow that so errors.

Comment: use AJAX get results in json and create DOM object. The way you've done it makes no sense in using javascript.

Comment: You're using a variable `i`, but never assigning anything to that varable. And you don't do anything with `$row`, even though you're iterating over the rows returned by the query.

Comment: It's not clear why you're doing this with Javascript at all? Why doesn't the PHP fill in the DIV directly?

Comment: You shouldn't call `$(".ex").draggable()` and `$(".ex").droppable()` in this function. That operates on all members of the class, so you should do it just once after the loop is done, not every time through the loop.

Comment: Can you show me some example?

Answer (score 0):

`$("body").append('<div id="foo">blabla</div>')`

Or if you want to replace the content of your existing div.

`$('#newdiv').html('..whatever..')`

Comment: How about $('#newdiv').append

Comment: `$('#newdiv').append()` will append whatever is between the brackets to `#newdiv`. So you will have 
`<div id='newdiv'>blabla
<div id='appendedDiv'>appended div</div>
</div>`
Now that i read your question again, it seems that this is what you want. Misunderstood it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function createDiv() {
           $('#newdiv').append('<div id="div"'+i+'" class="ex" style="text-align:    left;">
                <div id="div"'+i+'" class= "square"><table border="0" class = "table" ><tr>
                <td width="51">Name:</td><td width="141"><input type="text" size="10" class = "name">
                </td></tr><tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" size="10" class = "title">
                </td></tr><tr><td>Contact:</td><td><input type="text" size="10"  class = "contact">
               </td></tr></table></div><img class="myimage"    ondblclick="changeimage(this)" border="0"src="images/white_contact.png" width="60" />    </div>');

            $( ".ex" ).draggable({containment:'parent',cursor:'pointer',opacity:0.6});
            $( ".ex" ).droppable();
        }

   </script>
<div id = "newdiv">

</div>    

$qry = "SELECT * from contact Where CustomerID='57'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
?>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      createDiv(); // will execute when it loads this line
   </script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
?>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      createDiv(); // will execute when it loads this line
   </script>

<?php
}
?>

Comment: it doesnt automatically generate the DIV

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
<?php 
    $qry = "SELECT * from contact Where CustomerID='57'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry); 
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  

    }       
?>
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="newdiv"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?=$count?>"/>
</body> 
</html>
```

JQUERY

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     createDiv();

      function createDiv(){
        var count = $('[name="count"]').val();
        for (var i=1;i<=count;i++) {
          $('#newdiv').append('<div id="div'+ i +'" class="ex" style="text-align: left;"><div id="div'+ i +'" class= "square"><table border="0" class = "table" ><tr><td width="51">Name:</td><td width="141"><input type="text" size="10" class = "name"></td></tr><tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" size="10" class = "title"></td></tr><tr><td>Contact:</td><td><input type="text" size="10"  class = "contact"></td></tr></table></div><img class="myimage" ondblclick="changeimage(this)" border="0"src="images/white_contact.png" width="60" /></div>');
        }
      }


    });
</script>
```